# Добавление класса DOM элементу на 1.5 секунды

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не получается реализовать такую логику - нужно навешивать элементу класс со свойством `pointer-events: none;` на 1.5 секунды после изменения `state`.

```js
import ball from './img/ball.png';

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      position: 0
    }
  }
  
  changePosition = () => {
    this.setState({
      position: ++this.state.position
    })
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
      
    }, 1500)
    
    
  }
  
  render() {
    let boxStyle = styles.box;
    let pointerEvent = ` ${styles.box_inactive}`;
    
    if (this.state.position === 1) {
      boxStyle += pointerEvent; // это мне нужно засунуть в setTimeout , но,  как я понял нельзя это делать внутри render (я про setTimeout), но где тогда это можно сделать? нужно повесить класс на 1.5 секунды и снять его
    }
    
    
    return(
      <div className={boxStyle}>
        <img className={styles.ball} onClick={this.changePosition} src={ball}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос добавлением еще одного свойства состояния

```
this.state = {
    deerPosition: 0,
    isClickable: true
};


setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({
     isClickable: true
  })
}, 1600);
```

ну и отрывок простой логики

```
if (!this.state.isClickable) {
    boxStyle += pointerEvent;
}
```